# How to get properties from .env file in spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables, junit5

I am trying to setup tests for my spring-boot application. In regular execution I get some values from .env file that I've specified in run configuration and get them like so:

```java
 @Value("${jdbc.url}")
 private String jdbcUrl;
```

But when I try to run the simplest of tests, it fails with the exception :

> Failed to load ApplicationContext
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext........
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.url' in value "${jdbc.url}"

How do I load properties from the environment in SpringBootTest?

Here's my test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {App.class})
public class TestingWebApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an application.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your property to this location /src/test/resources/application-test.properties

Add an @ActiveProfiles("test") annotation on the test class and it should be picked up.
See screenshot below;

[You can use a profile specific application-{profile}.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NIRn.png)